# How could I select all inputs with value greater than 0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of text inputs with numeric values:

```
<input type='text' value='25' />
<input type='text' value='0' />
<input type='text' value='45' />
<input type='text' value='-2' />
.
. etc...
```

I need to select only those inputs with values greater than 0.  How can I do that using jQuery?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Something like this, using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > 0;
});
```

Comment: Can you try running this:  `alert(parseInt("08"));`  and `alert(parseInt("08", 10));`

Comment: @Cybernate: Oh I get it, yeah I'll add the radix. Thanks.

Comment: @Cybernate - Isn't 2nd param in parseInt() a base?  And if it's null, then it defaults to 10 based on the value of 1st param?

Comment: @Chandu Well, both gave 8?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk: As per: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/radix,  "ECMAScript 5 changed the behavior of parseInt() so that it no longer autodetects octal literals and instead treats them as decimal literals", hence you see 8 if you are running the code against ES 5  or above implementation

Answer (score 4):

```
//select all text type inputs
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if(val > 0)
        //your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way, for fun, mostly:

```
// get array of values
var arr = $('input').map(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10);
}).get();

// use John Resig's uberfast way of getting max value
// http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/
alert(Math.max.apply(Math, arr));
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/5qzhx/2/)

Note - the above works just fine without `parseInt`.